# Use javascript to randomly append CSS class to one list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random

Hey, I don't have any code because I don't know how to do this.  I'm looking to use jQuery / javascript to randomly append the CSS class "active" to one list item within a an unordered list id'd as ul#sliding_panels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it simple. This retrieves all the list items under that list:

```
var items = $("#sliding_panels li");
```

Then use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Math/Random) to pick one of them. **Note:** the construct `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))` will return an integer between 0 and 9 inclusive.

```
var item = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
```

You can use the array index operator on a jQuery object to retrieve one of those elements. **Note:** `set[n]` is equivalent to `set.get(n)` if `set` is a jQuery object.

You then need to wrap that element in a jQuery object and use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
$(items[item]).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764160/jquery-select-random-elements) for how to grab a random element.

```
$("#sliding_panels li").get().sort(function(){ 
  return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
}).slice(0,1).addClass("active");
```

Credit to [duckyflip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7370/duckyflip) for the original answer.

An alternative is the [:random plugin](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/) mentioned in the same question.

Example:

```
$("#sliding_panels li:random").addClass("active");
```

Comment: I don't get this. Why sort for selecting a random element? It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = $('ul#mylist li');
$ (elements.get (
  Math.round (elements.length*Math.random ()-0.5)
)).addClass ('active');
```