# Select maxium 5 li items with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, select

I have a `<ul>` with a lot of `<li>` You can see this here:

```
<ul>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/pon.jpg" alt="PON" width="111" height="63" /></li>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/spo.png" alt="SPO Utrecht" width="130" height="67" /></li>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/campus.jpg" alt="Onderwijs Campus" width="137" height="86" /></li>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/cpwb.png" alt="CPWB" width="112" height="99"/></li>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/expertis.jpg" alt="Expertis" width="120" height="56" /></li>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/inos.jpg" alt="Inos" width="211" height="67" /></li>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/OSG.jpg" alt="OSG" width="130" height="51" /></li>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/pio.png" alt="Pio" width="138" height="92" /></li>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/Signum.png" alt="Signum" width="181" height="68" /></li>
                        <li><img src="content/img/logos/vgs.png" alt="VGS" width="192" height="63" /></li>
                    </ul>
```

But no my question. The li items have his own `<img>` tag. But i want make, that jquery show me 5 li items. How can i make with javascript / jquery. That he show me random 5 of this li items?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
randomElements = jQuery("li").get().sort(function(){ 
  return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
}).slice(0,5)
```

Found in [*jQuery: select random elements*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764160/jquery-select-random-elements/1764629#1764629).

---

As for the question posed by OP in the comments:

```
var $allLi = $('ul li'), // All
    showRandom = function() {
        $allLi.hide().sort(function() { // Hide all, then sort
            return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
        }).slice(0, 5).show(); // Show first five after randomizing
    };

showRandom(); // Do it now ...
setInterval(showRandom, 1500); // ... and every 1.5 sec
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/6qY37/1/))

Comment: You can remove the `.get()` if you want the `jQuery` object back, not a collection of `DOMElement` s. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/6qY37/)

Comment: But how can i make. That he now rotate. That he every 10 sec show other li

Comment: @Mike Well that's another question, but I'd say that every then seconds you hide all (`$('li', container).hide()`) and then show five random (`$('li', container).sort(function() { return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5; }).slice(0, 5).show()`).

Answer (score 0):

When you are able to reference the li's, you'll be able to iterate it's children. Which are the li's. 
Example:

```
   $('li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
  });
```

In the example above, you can reference to the li's with $(this).
What you could do is store them in an array and fetch 5 randomly. You could do this using the Math.random method. Either rebuild the ul li list afterwards or remove the unwanted items with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var li = $('ul li');
var len =li.length;

while($('ul li:visible').length > 5) {
    li.eq(parseInt(len * Math.random())).hide();
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/yn92C/)