# Need a jQuery randomly selected identifier from options available

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to randomly select an id or value from one of the many option items in my select tag.  Also I was wandering how do I quickly count all the option tags in my select tag, and how can I randomly call an ID field efficiently so if I hit refresh, it will just pick another random id?  This is for a testing environment to auto fill a form out for qa people.

Examples

```
<select id="selectVendor">
 <option value="55" selected="selected">Company A</option>
 <option value="56">Company B</option>
 <option value="57">Company XYZCYK</option>
... </select>
```

Finally I want to put the value of my selected id into my form field... Eventually I want to use ajax to populate my entire form with the randomly selected identifier when the page first loads. thx

```
<input type="text" id="txtCompany" value="empty" />
```

Comment: How about [Select random elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764160/jquery-select-random-elements) or [Getting random value from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/javascript-getting-random-value-from-an-array) or the [MDN documentation of `Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var options = $("#selectVendor > option");

var random = Math.floor(options.length * (Math.random() % 1));

options.attr('selected',false)
.eq(random).attr('selected',true);
```

Sample at jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LV8ty/).

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("#txtCompany").val(
       $("#selectVendor option").eq(
         Math.floor(Math.random() * $("#selectVendor option").length + 1)
         ).val());
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rkMYB/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selectVendor option').size();
```

Will give you the options number.

```
var randomOption=Math.floor(Math.random()*$('#selectVendor option').size());
$("#selectVendor option[value='"+randomOption+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Will select a random option.

Comment: randomOption is not distributed uniformly across all possible options in your example. Also, you're not rounding at all. Won't work.

Comment: Sorry, i added the rounding, but I'm not sure I understand why you say *randomOption is not distributed uniformly across all possible options*, can you explain me, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy to read jsfiddle to get you going. http://jsfiddle.net/z5aHm/15/

Takes the number of options there are, generates a random number between 0 and the number of options, and grabs the value of the option at that index.