# jquery/javascript select option randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I want to select an option from select randomly.

```
<select class=".sel" id="sel">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
</select>
```

actually i am using jQuery autocomplete.

Well,the question is how can i select option randomly from a select box ?

and what i tried is

```
function change_something(opt)
    {
    var randomOption=Math.floor(Math.random()*$(opt+' option').size());
    $(opt+ option["value='"+randomOption+"'"]).attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
```

Actually i am not a jQuery expert,so i am getting failed to change something .

Comment: where is the question? where is your code?

Comment: @elclanrs Thank ou for the contribution to the question,i tried something `
 var randomOption=Math.floor(Math.random()*$(opt+' option').size());
$(opt+ option["value='"+randomOption+"'"]).attr('selected', 'selected');`

Comment: how about looking at this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577047/need-a-jquery-randomly-selected-identifier-from-options-available

Answer (score 11):

Something like this should work:

```
var $options = $('#sel').find('option'),
    random = ~~(Math.random() * $options.length);

$options.eq(random).prop('selected', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/8DPMN/

Answer (score 6):

That's what you need

```
options = $("#sel > option")
options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)].selected = true
```

Also, use class="sel" instead of class=".sel"

Comment: Did you try this?  It doesn't seem to work for me in Chrome.  It only works for me if I set `xxx.selected = "selected"`.

Comment: @jfriend00 i changed `.sel` to `sel` :D

Comment: @jfriend00: Are you setting the attribute? The property should be boolean as shown.

Answer (score 3):

This will work with your HTML example snippet.

```
var options = $("#sel > option");

var random = Math.floor(options.length * (Math.random() % 1));

$("#sel > option").attr('selected',false).eq(random).attr('selected',true);
```

Comment: what if i want to select one of those options randomly except the first option? (usually empty option) – andufo just now   edit

Answer (score -1):

Change your class from **".sel" to "sel"**, then Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".sel option").length) + 1;
  $("select option:nth-child(" + index + ")").prop("selected", true);
});
```