# trigger mouse enter on random element

Tags: jquery, random, eventtrigger

I have this javascript:

```
$('.foto').filter(function(index) {
    return index == Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
}).trigger('mouseover');
```

I want to simulate a hover effect on a photo, but somehow the filter function does not work.
I also tried

```
$('.foto:random').trigger('mouseover');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: select random elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764160/jquery-select-random-elements)

Comment: I've seen that but it did not work to me

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Lgn/. Maybe you thought that the whole construction returns a jQuery object, but it does not. `.get()` returns an array and `.sort()` and `.slice()` are native array methods. In my example I omitted `.get()`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense in the way you put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.fn.rand = function(){
    return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length));
};
$(".foto").rand().trigger("mouseover");
```

**Note:** you only have to define `$.fn.rand` once, usually right after including jquery.