# mouseenter without moving the Mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using mouseenter in jQuery with a previous/next button.  What I'm doing is clicking the next button to go to the next page.  I then have to move my mouse just slightly to trigger the 'mouseenter' piece to show my button again.  I want to eliminate that slight movement to show the button.  Is there a better way to do this?

My code is below:

```
    $('.rsSlide, .rsArrow').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('.rsArrow').removeClass('rsHidden');
    });
```

Comment: Not sure, would also capturing mouseover work?

Comment: You should be showing the button as part of your page load, or as a callback on the content update, and not as a result of user interaction.

Comment: If the mouse hasn't moved then there's no mouse event.  You'll likely need to use `trigger` at the appropriate time to call the code.

Comment: Check this out:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525555/trigger-mouse-enter-on-random-element

Comment: `$('.rsSlide, .rsArrow').trigger('mouseenter');`