# given a long list, how can i select x elements randomly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, jquery-selectors

Markup:

```
<ul>
<li>Bla</li>
<li>Ble</li>

...


<li>zla</li>
</ul>
```

Lets asume its a really long list, how can i select x items, but randomlly?

-edit-

Not exact duplicate, i am trying to select x items;

```
something like:
var i = 0;
$("li:random").each(function(){
    i++; if(i==50) break;
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: select random elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764160/jquery-select-random-elements)

Comment: @Esailija is not exact duplicate, i think

Comment: I don't understand how this question is getting downvotes with so many answers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how to get this using javascript [random](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) function:

```
$(function() {
    var randomItemsNum = 3;
    var totalItems = $('#mylist > li').length;

    for (var index = 0; index < randomItemsNum; index++) {
        var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * totalItems) + 1);
        var item = $('#mylist > li:nth-child(' + randomIndex + ')');
        if (item.hasClass('selected')) {
            index--;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            item.addClass('selected');
        }
    }
});
```

It adds CSS class selected to 3 random list items. Check working demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/PPW9J/1/

Comment: And what if the same element is selected twice?

Comment: You are right, I've updated the fiddle to fix this - http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/PPW9J/1/

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet my answer avoids duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```
function selectRandomFromList($list, num){
    var $children = $list.children(),
        len = $children.length,
        a = [],
        o = {},
        r,
        $items = $([]);

    if (!len) { return $items; }
    if (num >= len) { return $children; }

    // Build an array of unique indices
    while (a.length < num) {
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
        if (!o.hasOwnProperty(r)) {
            o[r] = 1;
            a.push(r);
        }
    }

    // grab the items
    while (num--) {
        $items = $items.add($children.eq(a.pop()));
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Example usage:

```
selectRandomFromList($('ul'), 3);
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/d8JgP/

Comment: I see that it checks if there are less items? thats awesome

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose a random number (r) between 1 and the length of the list.
2. Pick all elements where el# % r == 0.

Done. :)

Comment: How does this select a given number of items?  It seems to select a random number of items instead.

Comment: @apsillers thanks!, yes please Esteban, can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get away with doing something like this:

```
var list_length = $("ul li").length;
var x; //Assign amount of items
for(var i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
   Math.floor((Math.random()*list_length));
   //Select stuff in here
}
```

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet It get's the amount of list items, and for however many things you want randomly selected, will generate a random number from 0 to the maximum amount of list items.

Comment: but how do i select there? $('ul li')[i] ?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet You could do `$("li").eq(i)` to select the element.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:-

```
randomList = 8;

randomElements = jQuery("li").get().sort(function(){ 
  return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
}).slice(0,randomList);

$(randomElements).addClass("activeLI");​
```

### CSS

```
.activeLI {
    color: red;
}​
```

Change randomList number **8** to **50** or any number.

Refer to the **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/qQJXg/2/)**

*copied from [jQuery: select random elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764629/500725) this answer.*