# Add Class to DIV in random sequence

Tags: jquery, sequence

I am looking to find a way in jQuery to randomly add a class to a range of DIVs over a period of time until they all have had the new class added to them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cardWrapper > div").addClass('flip');
});
```

This works to add the class 'flip' to the DIVs inside the .cardWrapper DIV, but what I need is for the addclass action to happen one at a time and ideally in a random fashion - so basically, each of the 10 DIVs gets the 'flip' class added to it in a random sequence with a definable delay inbetween each addclass being added...

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Look into [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval), `setTimeout` etc for the delay and [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) for choosing the element, it's pretty self-explanatory from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $divs = $(".cardWrapper > div");
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var $ds = $divs.not(".flip");
        $ds.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $ds.length)).addClass('flip');
        if ($ds.length == 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tj6ep/)

Comment: Leg end! Works like a dream! Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Given the shuffle, you can then pick X elements at random with

```
var items = shuffle($(".cardWrapper")).slice(0, X);
```

Then you can apply your class for the item.

This is how I did for my requirement. The logic is from [jQuery select random elements with same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186631/jquery-select-random-elements-with-same-class)