# Select 2 random divs with the same class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my question is simple, suppose I have 10 divs:

```
<div class="someDiv"></div>
<div class="someDiv"></div>
<div class="someDiv"></div>
<div class="someDiv"></div>
<div class="someDiv"></div>
<div class="someDiv"></div>
<div class="someDiv"></div>
<div class="someDiv"></div>
<div class="someDiv"></div>
<div class="someDiv"></div>
```

And I want that when I click 'foo' just 2 of the divs change their background to red. How can I achieve this with something like Math.random from js?

Comment: wheres 'foo' there? is it a button?

Comment: doesnt matter, `$('.foo').click(function(){});` whatever

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11186765/2000051

Comment: already read that anwser, I'm not able to understand it but I'll give it a second try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this** - Use [Math.Random](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) and [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

**[Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/5qnffmty/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var r1 = (Math.random()*10);
    var r2 = (Math.random()*10); 
    if(parseInt(r1)==parseInt(r2)) // IF BOTH ARE SAME
    {
       if(parseInt(r1)==10)
       {
           r2=r2-1;
       }
       else
       {
          r2=r2+1;
       }
    }   
    var allDiv = $('.someDiv');    
    $(allDiv[parseInt(r1)]).css({'background':'red'});
    $(allDiv[parseInt(r2)]).css({'background':'red'});
});
```

Comment: Glad to help you :) please `accept` the answer it will helps other to find correct solution.

Comment: @prog Sometime `r1` and `r2` will be equal, e.g. `r1 = r2 = 1` then the `background` of `div1 ` will change not 2 `div`, how we can resolve this ?

Comment: @aria - if `r1 =r2=1` at that time you can check `if (r1==10) { r2=r2-1 } else {r2=r2+1;}`

Comment: @Prog Yes that is work now, or the other solution can be `while(r1==r2){ r2 = (Math.random()*10); }`

Answer (score 2):

A generalized approach for specified number of elements to change.
just change `var numOfDivToChange=2;` to apply the effect to more elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var numOfDivToChange=2;
    $('.foo').click(function(){


        //get all similar elements array
        var allFoos = document.getElementsByClassName('someDiv');

        //sanity check
        if(numOfDivToChange>allFoos)
             return false;

        for(var i=0;i<numOfDivToChange;i++)
        { 
           //generate a random index
           var   randIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * allFoos.length) + 1);

           //set the css changes you want
           allFoos[randIndex].css('background','red');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplified version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/11186765/2000051

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/fK8Xw/69/

JS:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var m = array.length,
        t, i;
    while (m) {
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    }
    return array;
}

$(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var $all = $(".someDiv").removeClass("red");
        $(shuffle($all).slice(0, 3)).addClass("red");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.foo').click(function(){
        var rand1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var rand2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('someDiv')[rand1];
        var b = document.getElementsByClassName('someDiv')[rand2];
        a.css('background','red');
        b.css('background','red');
    });
});
```

Comment: updated , check now, it was 'getElementsByClassName'