# How to pick random few slides for jssor slider and hide the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, jssor

I have 8 slides and I want to show random 3 every time user refresh the page. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Once you refresh you loose context, so you need to play with localStorage. Justsomewhat [Related](http://vinayakjadhav.github.io/jRCarousel/)

Comment: And from Jssor API: `$PlayTo(slideIndex[, slideDuration])
//Play slider to position 'slideIndex' within a period calculated base on 'slideDuration'`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't explain it properly. PlayTo is for the slides to go to certain slide. I need the jssor to just show 3 and hide the rest. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how you have implemented the jssor in your page. on `onready` event you can select any random 3 images div & detach them then call the plugin on container div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to put the slides in another div and hide it. Then using solution from: [jQuery select random elements with same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186631/jquery-select-random-elements-with-same-class), I slice 3 of the div and then duplicate it into the jssor slide.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

  // Pick a remaining element…
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

  // And swap it with the current element.
  t = array[m];
  array[m] = array[i];
  array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $all = $(".all-slides > div").removeClass("selected");
    $(shuffle($all).slice(0, 3)).addClass("selected");
    $( ".selected" ).appendTo( ".slides" );
        var options = {
            $DragOrientation: 0,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider_container", options);
});
```