# Need help from jquery/javascript genius - Put random items in flexgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to impliment a flex grid in my solution.
If you look at this grid: http://tympanus.net/Development/GammaGallery/

You can see that it works fine, now what I would like to achieve is put random white squares between the pictures, so no white pictures but white squares/rectangles.

I would load the images from contentitems so that's why i can't use white images.

If anyone would have an idea how to accomplish this it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.Hope that helps.

```
randomElements = $('.masonry-brick').get().sort(function(){ 
  return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
}).slice(0,1)
$(randomElements).html('<div></div>');
```

inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764160/select-5-random-elements).for div keep the css whatever you want, like white background etc.check out the screen shots.

[image: before div]
[image: after div]

Comment: I've tried:  <script>
$(function ()
{
var randomElements = $('.masonry-brick').get().sort(function(){ 
  return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
}).slice(0,1)
randomElements.html('<div></div>');
});
</script> but the error is: TypeError: randomElements.html is not a function

Comment: try $(randomElements).html('<div></div>'); It will work. Dont forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Then the window just keeps loading, infinite loop? the source is here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/06/gamma-gallery-a-responsive-image-gallery-experiment/

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm a complete jq noob, how should i put the script exactly in my html file?

Comment: I have updated the answer you just have to copy it and use it as per your needs for example you can put it on a button click, on-load or any other event. In-case you face any problems you always have stackoverflow. Please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: ok, used window.onload, thanks a lot!!!, last question, is this code replacing one of the images or just adding one, also, it only puts one empty one, how can i get more?

Comment: you can put this code in a function and run that function number of times.Moreover I would recommend you to go through jquery docs so that it will help you learn this stuff very quickly.hope this answers all of your queries.check this post on functions(http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/), please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: ok, i've put in 3 in the slice number and now i have 3 empty spaces, it seems it only works on the last list, how can i put spaces in all of the lists?

Comment: sorry misunderstood your previous comment.It is random.