# jQuery add class to 6 random elements with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have 12 elements with class "block" and I need to add class "active" to 6 of 12 elements (randomly).

I think using for loop would to the trick but I am not sure how to do it. Maybe somebody can help me out?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    block.eq(random % block.length).addClass("active");

}
```

This code adds class, but it's not 6 elements every time.. Need a solution to add "active" class to 6 elements every time. Now sometimes it's 6, sometime less..

Comment: xoomer, in the linked question you probably want the [answer by  Alexander Wallin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786412/182660) rather than accepted one.

Comment: thats a very complex code :D

Comment: that's the price for it being reliable in selecting exactly half of all elements.

Answer (score -1):

you can select all elements first and by random function chose any six of them and add class active to them

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName(elementname);

for(var i =0; i<6 ; i++)
 var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11) + 1);
 element[random].className += "active";
```

Comment: but how to do it using jquery?

Comment: this code is logically the same as what OP has and it will **_not_** produce **_exactly_** 6 elements every time as `random` might get the same value on 2 different iterations